# If $f$ is continuous, increasing and not bounded, then there is $x$ such that $f(x) - f(-x) = 1$.

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f : \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ be continuous, increasing and unbounded. I want to show that there is $x \in \mathbb R$ such that $f(x) - f(-x) = 1$. To me it looks like one needs to apply the intermediate value theorem to the function $g(x) = f(x) - f(-x)$ but I am unsure how:

Since $f$ is incresing one knows for $x \geq 0$ that $f(-x) \leq f(x)$ and therefore $-f(x) \geq -f(-x)$. For $x \leq 0$ one has $f(x) \leq f(-x)$. This means that the function $g(x) = f(x) - f(-x)$ is positive on the positive real line and negative real line. Hence, one would like to show that there is $x \geq 0$ such that $g(x) = 1$.

Now since $f$ is unbounded, one can find $y \geq 0$ such that e.g. $f(y) > 2$. Then
$$g(y) = f(y) - f(-y) > 2 - f(-y).$$
But I don't see how that yields anywhere. Any suggestions?

Comment: Unbounded at both $\infty$ and $-\infty$?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Consider
$$g : x \mapsto f(x)-f(-x)$$

$g$ is continuous, and one has $g(0)=0$ and $\lim_{x \rightarrow + \infty} g(x) = +\infty$ (because $f$ is increasing and unbounded). Therefore, by the IVT, there exists $x \geq 0$ such that
$$g(x)=1$$
i.e.
$$f(x)-f(-x)=1$$

Answer (score 2):

If $f$ is not bounded above then $g(0)=0$ and $g(x)=f(x)-f(-x)\geq f(x)-f(0)$ for $x \geq 0$. Hence $g(0)=0$ and $g(x) >1$ for some $x >0$. It follows that $g(x)=1$ for some $x$. The case when $f$ is unbounded below is similar.